# Evaluating strings against boolean truth functions

Tags: python, logic, boolean, nltk, boolean-logic

I've searched and still don't have a clue here, so please bear with me.

I have strings, each corresponding to a particular *feature matrix*. Examples:

```
'a' = [-vegetable, +fruit, +apple, -orange]
'o' = [-vegetable, +fruit, -apple, +orange]
't' = [+vegetable, -fruit, -apple, -orange]
```

Note that this is just the notation I've chosen to represent the matrices here.

What I want to be able to do is take any number of such strings and evaluate them against some number of truth functions. So, evaluating the string 'aoaot' against:

```
[+fruit] => [+apple]
equivalently: (not [+fruit]) or [+apple]
```

should return the number of times this implication is false for the given string. Either something like this:

```
[True, False, True, False, True]
```

Or an absolute count of the number of evaluations to False, e.g. 2 here. What would be the sensible way to do this in python? I'm looking into NLTK but am unsure.

Comment: Unless you want to parse queries posed in natural language, you don't need NLTK. Parsing boolean expressions, even if arbitary nesting is allowed, is rather simple with most parsing technologies (almost trivial with some).

Comment: I do. I'm attempting to make an optimality-theoretic eval() function for phonological constraint ranking.

Comment: If 't' stands for 'tomato', this is actually a fruit, at least botanically-speaking. http://oxforddictionaries.com/page/tomatofruitveg

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the necessary logic using the `set` type.

```
m = {
    'a':set(['fruit', 'apple']),
    'o':set(['fruit', 'orange']),
    't':set(['vegetable'])
}

pred = lambda f: ('fruit' in f) <= ('apple' in f)

# True/False array
[ pred(m[f]) for f in 'aoaot' ]

# Number of falses
sum( not pred(m[f]) for f in 'aoaot' )
```

Comment: What exactly is being compared here?

Comment: `('fruit' in f) <= ('apple' in f)` returns true if f has no fruit or it has an apple.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have more flexibility in your own syntax, here is a simple parser for the data definitions you've given:

```
data = """\
a = [-vegetable, +fruit, +apple, -orange, -citrus] 
o = [-vegetable, +fruit, -apple, +orange, +citrus] 
t = [+vegetable, -fruit]"""

from pyparsing import Word, alphas, oneOf, Group, delimitedList

# a basic token for a word of alpha characters plus underscores
ident = Word(alphas + '_')

# define a token for leading '+' or '-', with parse action to convert to bool value
inclFlag = oneOf('+ -')
inclFlag.setParseAction(lambda t: t[0] == '+')

# define a feature as the combination of an inclFlag and a feature name
feature = Group(inclFlag('has') + ident('feature'))

# define a definition
defn = ident('name') + '=' + '[' + delimitedList(feature)('features') + ']'

# search through the input test data for defns, and print out the parsed data
# by name, and the associated features
defns = defn.searchString(data)
for d in defns:
    print d.dump()
    for f in d.features:
        print f.dump('  ')
    print
```

Prints:

```
['a', '=', '[', [False, 'vegetable'], [True, 'fruit'], [True, 'apple'], [False, 'orange'], [False, 'citrus'], ']']
- features: [[False, 'vegetable'], [True, 'fruit'], [True, 'apple'], [False, 'orange'], [False, 'citrus']]
- name: a
  [False, 'vegetable']
  - feature: vegetable
  - has: False
  [True, 'fruit']
  - feature: fruit
  - has: True
  [True, 'apple']
  - feature: apple
  - has: True
  [False, 'orange']
  - feature: orange
  - has: False
  [False, 'citrus']
  - feature: citrus
  - has: False

['o', '=', '[', [False, 'vegetable'], [True, 'fruit'], [False, 'apple'], [True, 'orange'], [True, 'citrus'], ']']
- features: [[False, 'vegetable'], [True, 'fruit'], [False, 'apple'], [True, 'orange'], [True, 'citrus']]
- name: o
  [False, 'vegetable']
  - feature: vegetable
  - has: False
  [True, 'fruit']
  - feature: fruit
  - has: True
  [False, 'apple']
  - feature: apple
  - has: False
  [True, 'orange']
  - feature: orange
  - has: True
  [True, 'citrus']
  - feature: citrus
  - has: True

['t', '=', '[', [True, 'vegetable'], [False, 'fruit'], ']']
- features: [[True, 'vegetable'], [False, 'fruit']]
- name: t
  [True, 'vegetable']
  - feature: vegetable
  - has: True
  [False, 'fruit']
  - feature: fruit
  - has: False
```

Pyparsing does much of the overhead stuff for you, like iterating over the input string, skipping irrelevant whitespace, and returning the parsed data using named attributes.  Check out the boolean evaluator at the pyparsing wiki (SimpleBool.py), or the more complete boolean evaluator package booleano.